# Running a job with FlinkRunner in google cloud fails because of missing project id

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-flink, google-cloud-dataflow

I need to run a batch job that essentially reads from big query and publishes to pubsub topic. I used to use dataflow for that but for some security reason dataflow should be removed. As a first replacement I tried DirectRunner but since it is not designed for production use and the datasource is huge, I get OutOfMemory exception. Now I am trying to use FlinkRunner.
This is my FlinkPipelineOptions

```
FlinkPipelineOptions {
    val options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create().`as`(FlinkPipelineOptions::class.java)
    options.jobName = jobName
    options.runner = FlinkRunner::class.java
    options.tempLocation = bigQueryProperties.tempLocation
    options.checkpointingMode = CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE.name
    options.maxParallelism = 2
    options.shutdownSourcesAfterIdleMs = 20000

    return options
}
```

but when I run the job, even before starting, this exception happens:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not create input splits from Source.
at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.SourceInputFormat.createInputSplits(SourceInputFormat.java:124)
at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.SourceInputFormat.createInputSplits(SourceInputFormat.java:42)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionJobVertex.initialize(ExecutionJobVertex.java:246)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Required parameter projectId must be specified.
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:907)
at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:138)
at com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery$Jobs$Insert.<init>(Bigquery.java:1738)
at com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery$Jobs.insert(Bigquery.java:1688)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$JobServiceImpl.dryRunQuery(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:477)
```

There is no way to set a projectId or project in Flink pipeline.

p.s. I tried flink runner with dataflow pipeline but it is failing for some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

The error which indicates the `NullPointerException` in the BigQuery source when trying to create input splits for your **Flink job** suggests that the `"projectId"` parameter is missing or not properly specified when interacting with BigQuery.

To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that you provide the correct "projectId" parameter when setting up the BigQuery source in your Flink job. The BigQuery source requires the project ID to identify the Google Cloud project where the BigQuery data resides. You can add this line of code:

```
// Set the Google Cloud project ID for the BigQuery source
    options.setProject("your-gcp-project-id")
```

By setting the project ID properly in your BigQuery source configuration, you should be able to resolve the NullPointerException.